# Update field of onetoone related model with django form

Tags: django, django-forms

In models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = AutoOneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_avatars/', default = 'user_avatars/default-avatar.jpg')
    male = 'M'
    female = 'F'
    gender_choices = ((male,'Male'), (female,'Female'))
    gender = models.CharField(choices = gender_choices, max_length = 10)
    dateOfBirth = models.DateField(default = datetime.date.today)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name = 'followers', symmetrical=False,\
                                        blank = True)
    favorite_pet = models.ManyToManyField(Pet, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

In forms.py:

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name')
    email = forms.EmailField()
    gender_choices = (('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'))
    gender = models.CharField(choices=gender_choices, max_length=10)
    dateOfBirth = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
```

I want to allow users to change their `gender` and `dateOfBirth`. However, these fields belong to `UserProfile` class (which has one-to-one relationship with `User`), thus if I add 'gender' and 'dateOfBirth' to array fields in meta class I will get "unknown fields" error from `User` class. Could anyone show me how to achieve  my goal? Any help will be highly appreciated :D

Comment: A little detail, you could declare a choice list `GENDER_CHOICES =(('M', 'Male'),('F', 'Female'))` and in `gender_choices = models.CharField (
        'Gender',
        max_length = 1,
        choices = GENDER_CHOICES,
    )` instead of declaring two fields.

Comment: Also your EditProfileForm is wrong, you're declaring fields calling a models.AnyField. The choices are provided by the model, you don't need to declare it again.

Answer (score 0):

Have the User model add a method that calls it's related UserProfile instance and updates it.  I've typically done it by calling the instance as a variable, but I believe you can access it directly through the instance attribute that holds the ForeignKey/ManytoMany, etc.

```
class User(models.Model):
attributes = models.Fields()
user_profile = models.ForeignKey()

def update_profile(self):
    self.user_profile.gender = self.gender
    self.user_profile.DateOfBirth = self.date_of_birth
    self.user_profile.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @bubthegreat though I am still confused with your answer (my `UserProfile` model has one-to-one relationship with default `User` in `django.contrib.auth.models`, not one created by hand like yours).

I figured out how to solve my problem. In `views.py`:

```
def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    user_form = UserForm(request.POST or None, \
                        initial={'first_name': user.first_name, 'last_name': user.last_name,
                                 'email': user.email}, instance = request.user)
    user_profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, \
                        initial={'gender': user.userprofile.gender, 'dateOfBirth': user.userprofile.dateOfBirth}, \
                        instance=request.user.userprofile)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if user_form.is_valid() and user_profile_form.is_valid():
            user.first_name = user_form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = user_form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.email = user_form.cleaned_data['email']
            user.userprofile.gender = user_profile_form.cleaned_data['gender']
            user.userprofile.dateOfBirth = user_profile_form.cleaned_data['dateOfBirth']
            user.save()
            user.userprofile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('pet:current user profile'))
    context = {
        "user_form": user_form,
        "user_profile_form": user_profile_form
    }
    return render(request, "edit_profile.html", context)
```

In `forms.py`:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('gender', 'dateOfBirth')
```